# Why wont my ball object continously move up when i press space?

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to recreate the mini game shooting gallery from Zelda: A link to the past with a triangle polygon that acts as the player and a circle that acts as the projectile and when  the player presses space the projectile moves up at a quick speed, but my setOnKeyPressed method does not work, what am i missing?

> Method spoken about

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                Command movement = keyCommands.get(event.getCode());
                if (movement != null){
                    movement.execute(player);
                }
                
                Command shoot = keyCommandsBall.get(event.getCode());
                if (shoot != null){
                    shoot.execute(ball);
                }
                
            }
        });
```

> This is my main method

```
package videogameclass;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class VideoGameClass extends Application {
    
   

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        
        
      stage.setTitle("Target practice");
      
      Group root = new Group();
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240);
      stage.setScene(scene);
        
      Circle circle1 = new Circle(20,20,10);
      Sprite c = new Sprite(circle1);
      circle1.setFill(Color.RED);
      root.getChildren().add(c.getNode());
      
      Circle circle2 = new Circle(80, 20, 10);
      Sprite c2 = new Sprite(circle2);
      circle2.setFill(Color.RED);
      root.getChildren().add(c2.getNode());
      
      Circle circle3 = new Circle(140, 20, 10);
      Sprite c3 = new Sprite(circle3);
      circle3.setFill(Color.RED);
      root.getChildren().add(c3.getNode());
      
      
      
      Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(15,40,25,10);
      Sprite rec = new Sprite(rectangle);
      rectangle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
      root.getChildren().add(rec.getNode());
      
      Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(75,40,25,10);
      Sprite rec2 = new Sprite(rectangle2);
      rectangle2.setFill(Color.BLACK);
      root.getChildren().add(rec2.getNode());
      
      Rectangle rectangle3 = new Rectangle(135,40,25,10);
      Sprite rec3 = new Sprite(rectangle3);
      rectangle3.setFill(Color.BLACK);
      root.getChildren().add(rec3.getNode());
      
      Rectangle rectangle4 = new Rectangle(195,40,25,10);
      Sprite rec4 = new Sprite(rectangle4);
      rectangle4.setFill(Color.BLACK);
      root.getChildren().add(rec4.getNode());
      
      
      
       Polygon t = new Polygon();
        Sprite player = new Sprite(t);
        root.getChildren().add(player.getNode());
        t.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
            25.0, 20.0,
            45.0, 20.0,
            35.0, 5.0,
            25.0,20.0,
        });
        t.setTranslateX(125);
        t.setTranslateY(200);
      
        Circle circle4 = new Circle(t.getTranslateX()+35,t.getTranslateY(),5);
        Sprite ball = new Sprite(circle4);
        root.getChildren().add(ball.getNode());
        
      Command moveLeft = new Command() 
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(Sprite sprite)
            {
              
                sprite.setVelocity(-2, 0);
                //sprite.update();
                

            }

          
        };
        
        
       
        
        Command moveRight = new Command() 
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(Sprite sprite)
            {
                sprite.setVelocity(2, 0);
                //sprite.update();

            }
        };
        
        Command moveUp = new Command(){
            @Override
            public void execute(Sprite sprite){
                sprite.setVelocity(0,-2);
            }
        };
        
        
        Command stopMoving = new Command()
        {
            @Override
            public void execute(Sprite sprite)
            {
                sprite.setVelocity(0,0);
            }
            
        };
      
      Map<KeyCode,Command> keyCommands = new HashMap<>();
        keyCommands.put(KeyCode.LEFT, moveLeft);
        keyCommands.put(KeyCode.RIGHT, moveRight);
        
      Map<KeyCode,Command> keyCommandsBall = new HashMap<>();
        keyCommands.put(KeyCode.SPACE, moveUp);
        
        Map<KeyCode,Command> keyCommands2 = new HashMap<>();
        keyCommands.put(KeyCode.F19, moveLeft);
        keyCommands.put(KeyCode.F18, moveRight);
      
      AnimationTimer animation = new AnimationTimer()
      {
          @Override
          public void handle(long now){
              c.setVelocity(1.0, 0);
              c2.setVelocity(1.0,0);
              c3.setVelocity(1.0,0);
              
              ball.setVelocity(0, 0);
              
              rec.setVelocity(-2.0,0);
              rec2.setVelocity(-2.0,0);
              rec3.setVelocity(-2.0,0);
              rec4.setVelocity(-2.0,0);
              c.update();
              c2.update();
              c3.update();
              ball.update();//projectile 
              rec.update();
              rec2.update();
              rec3.update();
              rec4.update();
              player.update();
              //move sprites
              
              //check and handle collisions
              if(c3.getNode().getTranslateX() > scene.getWidth() - 120){
                  c3.getNode().setTranslateX(-140);
              }
              if(c2.getNode().getTranslateX() > scene.getWidth() - 75){
                  c2.getNode().setTranslateX(c3.getNode().getTranslateX()-20);
              }
              if(c.getNode().getTranslateX() > scene.getWidth() - 10){
                  c.getNode().setTranslateX(c2.getNode().getTranslateX()-20);
              }
              
              if (rec.getNode().getTranslateX() < -40){
                    rec.getNode().setTranslateX(300);
              }
              if(rec2.getNode().getTranslateX() < -100){
                  rec2.getNode().setTranslateX(rec.getNode().getTranslateX()+30);
              }
              if(rec3.getNode().getTranslateX() < -135){
                  rec3.getNode().setTranslateX(rec2.getNode().getTranslateX()+30);
              }
              if(rec4.getNode().getTranslateX() < -225){
                  rec4.getNode().setTranslateX(rec3.getNode().getTranslateX()+30);
              }
              
              if(ball.getNode().getBoundsInParent().intersects(rec.getNode().getBoundsInParent())){
            
                    ball.setVelocity(0, 0);     
        }
              if(ball.getNode().getBoundsInParent().intersects(rec2.getNode().getBoundsInParent())){
            
                    ball.setVelocity(0, 0);     
        }
              if(ball.getNode().getBoundsInParent().intersects(rec3.getNode().getBoundsInParent())){
            
                    ball.setVelocity(0, 0);     
        }
              if(ball.getNode().getBoundsInParent().intersects(rec4.getNode().getBoundsInParent())){
            
                    ball.setVelocity(0, 0);     
        }
              if(ball.getNode().getBoundsInParent().intersects(c.getNode().getBoundsInParent())){
            
                    ball.setVelocity(0, 0);     
        }
              if(ball.getNode().getBoundsInParent().intersects(c2.getNode().getBoundsInParent())){
            
                    ball.setVelocity(0, 0);     
        }
              if(ball.getNode().getBoundsInParent().intersects(c3.getNode().getBoundsInParent())){
            
                    ball.setVelocity(0, 0);     
        }
              
              
              
          }//end of handle
      };
      
      scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                Command movement = keyCommands.get(event.getCode());
                if (movement != null){
                    movement.execute(player);
                }
                Command shoot = keyCommandsBall.get(event.getCode());
                if (shoot != null){
                    shoot.execute(ball);
                }
                
            }
        });
      
      scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                Command movement = keyCommands2.get(event.getCode());
                Command stop = stopMoving;
                if (movement == null){
                    stop.execute(player);
                }
                
            }
            
        });
      
      
      
      
      
      animation.start();
        stage.show();
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

> This is my Sprite class

```
package videogameclass;
import javafx.scene.Node;
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Sprite {
    
    private final Node node;
    private double dx, dy;
    
    public Sprite(Node node){
        this.node = node;
    }
    public Node getNode(){
        return node;
    }
    public void setVelocity(double dx, double dy){
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    }
    public double getVelocityX(){
        return dx;
    }
    public double getVelocityY(){
        return dy;
    }
    public void update(){
        this.node.setTranslateX(this.node.getTranslateX()+dx);
        this.node.setTranslateY(this.node.getTranslateY()+dy);
    }
}
```

> This is my Command method

```
package videogameclass;


public interface Command
{
    public void execute(Sprite sprite);
    
}
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of code which immediately makes me ask for a [mcve]. Did you step through your code with a debugger already?

Comment: What do you mean by 'my setOnKeyPressed method does not work'? Is it not called, or does it produce unexpected results? What does it produce, and what is expected?

Answer (score 2):

Because there is nothing added to `keyCommandsBall` map.

I am not sure if this is a typo mistake, but I can sense this part of the code is wrong. All the commands added to `keyCommands` map only.

```
Map<KeyCode,Command> keyCommands = new HashMap<>();
keyCommands.put(KeyCode.LEFT, moveLeft);
keyCommands.put(KeyCode.RIGHT, moveRight);
        
Map<KeyCode,Command> keyCommandsBall = new HashMap<>();
keyCommands.put(KeyCode.SPACE, moveUp);
        
Map<KeyCode,Command> keyCommands2 = new HashMap<>();
keyCommands.put(KeyCode.F19, moveLeft);
keyCommands.put(KeyCode.F18, moveRight);
```

**Update:**

I felt a bit interesting in this game so I tried to put my hands in this. Indeed this was quite fun when playing ;)

But few suggestions for you from your code:

- Try to reuse to code by either keeping things in loop or by calling a common method. That way you can reduce the code drastically.
- Try to create constants for the fixed sizes and positions. That way you accidentally don't get messed up with some wrong values. (Though I have not included that in my example)
- When providing a minimal example, try to keep all the code in a single class with all imports (even if it has multiple classes or interfaces). The main aim should be that others should directly copy the class and should be able to run the program.

Below is the output of the code that I worked on. (There is still so much scope to optimize this)
[image]

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class VideoGameClass extends Application {
    private List<Sprite> circles = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Sprite> rectangles = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Sprite> all = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 320, 240, Color.BLACK);
        stage.setTitle("Target practice");
        stage.setScene(scene);

        Sprite c1 = createCircle(20, 20);
        Sprite c2 = createCircle(80, 20);
        Sprite c3 = createCircle(140, 20);

        Sprite rec1 = createRectangle(15);
        Sprite rec2 = createRectangle(75);
        Sprite rec3 = createRectangle(135);
        Sprite rec4 = createRectangle(195);

        Polygon t = new Polygon();
        t.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
                25.0, 20.0,
                45.0, 20.0,
                35.0, 5.0,
                25.0, 20.0,
        });
        t.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        t.setTranslateX(125);
        t.setTranslateY(200);
        Sprite player = new Sprite(t);
        all.add(player);

        Sprite ball = new Sprite(new Circle(t.getTranslateX() + 35, t.getTranslateY(), 5, Color.WHITE));
        all.add(ball);

        all.stream().map(Sprite::getNode).forEach(n -> root.getChildren().add(n));

        Command moveLeft = sprite -> sprite.setVelocity(-2, 0);
        Command moveRight = sprite -> sprite.setVelocity(2, 0);
        Command moveUp = sprite -> sprite.setVelocity(0, -2);
        Command stopMoving = sprite -> sprite.setVelocity(0, 0);

        Map<KeyCode, Command> keyCommands = new HashMap<>();
        keyCommands.put(KeyCode.LEFT, moveLeft);
        keyCommands.put(KeyCode.RIGHT, moveRight);

        Map<KeyCode, Command> keyCommandsBall = new HashMap<>();
        keyCommandsBall.put(KeyCode.SPACE, moveUp);

        Map<KeyCode, Command> keyCommands2 = new HashMap<>();
        keyCommands.put(KeyCode.F11, moveLeft);
        keyCommands.put(KeyCode.F12, moveRight);

        AnimationTimer animation = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                circles.forEach(c -> c.setVelocity(1.0, 0));
                rectangles.forEach(r -> r.setVelocity(-2.0, 0));
                all.forEach(Sprite::update);

                //check and handle collisions
                if (c3.getNode().getTranslateX() > scene.getWidth() - 120) {
                    c3.getNode().setTranslateX(-140);
                }
                if (c2.getNode().getTranslateX() > scene.getWidth() - 75) {
                    c2.getNode().setTranslateX(c3.getNode().getTranslateX() - 20);
                }
                if (c1.getNode().getTranslateX() > scene.getWidth() - 10) {
                    c1.getNode().setTranslateX(c2.getNode().getTranslateX() - 20);
                }

                if (rec1.getNode().getTranslateX() < -40) {
                    rec1.getNode().setTranslateX(300);
                }
                if (rec2.getNode().getTranslateX() < -100) {
                    rec2.getNode().setTranslateX(rec1.getNode().getTranslateX() + 30);
                }
                if (rec3.getNode().getTranslateX() < -135) {
                    rec3.getNode().setTranslateX(rec2.getNode().getTranslateX() + 30);
                }
                if (rec4.getNode().getTranslateX() < -225) {
                    rec4.getNode().setTranslateX(rec3.getNode().getTranslateX() + 30);
                }

                // Check for collision and stop the ball
                Stream.of(circles, rectangles).flatMap(List::stream).forEach(sprite -> {
                    if (ball.getNode().getBoundsInParent().intersects(sprite.getNode().getBoundsInParent())) {
                        ball.setVelocity(0, 0);
                    }
                });
            }//end of handle
        };

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            Command movement = keyCommands.get(event.getCode());
            if (movement != null) {
                movement.execute(player);
            }
            Command shoot = keyCommandsBall.get(event.getCode());
            if (shoot != null) {
                shoot.execute(ball);
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            Command movement = keyCommands2.get(event.getCode());
            Command stop = stopMoving;
            if (movement == null) {
                stop.execute(player);
            }

            // Bring back the ball to the player
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.Z){
                ball.setVelocity(0, 0);
                Circle ballNode = (Circle) ball.getNode();
                ballNode.setTranslateX(0);
                ballNode.setTranslateY(0);
                ballNode.setCenterX(player.getNode().getTranslateX() + 35);
                ballNode.setCenterY(player.getNode().getTranslateY());
            }
        });

        animation.start();
        stage.show();
    }

    private Sprite createCircle(double centerX, double centerY) {
        Sprite circle = new Sprite(new Circle(centerX, centerY, 10, Color.RED));
        circles.add(circle);
        all.add(circle);
        return circle;
    }

    private Sprite createRectangle(double x) {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(x, 40, 25, 10);
        r.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        Sprite rectangle = new Sprite(r);
        rectangles.add(rectangle);
        all.add(rectangle);
        return rectangle;
    }

    class Sprite {
        private final Node node;
        private double dx, dy;

        public Sprite(Node node) {
            this.node = node;
        }

        public Node getNode() {
            return node;
        }

        public void setVelocity(double dx, double dy) {
            this.dx = dx;
            this.dy = dy;
        }

        public void update() {
            this.node.setTranslateX(this.node.getTranslateX() + dx);
            this.node.setTranslateY(this.node.getTranslateY() + dy);
        }
    }

    interface Command {
        void execute(Sprite sprite);
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted for using `Command` as a functional interface, it makes the code more readable now :)